# I do separate the date-time data type into different columns in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

My data is in the format of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss a.m (or p.m). What I need to do is separate the date and time into 2 separate columns in excel

Answer (score 0):

Dates are always stored as integers in Excel's memory. So you need to use these 2 formulas

eg: Cell - A2 has your date i:e : 14/10/2022  11:52:00 AM

Formula-1: A3=int(A2)
Formula-2: A4=A2-int(A2) #Fromat this column as Time

Cheers :-)

Comment: In Office 365 you could spill them at once:`=LET(d,A2,date,INT(d),time,d-date,CHOOSE({1,2},date,time))`